# Linq GroupJoin with DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, linq

I have this GroupJoin:

```
var groupjoin = cData.GroupJoin(
            aData,
            c => c.Id,
            a => a.Id,
            (c, joined) => new { c, a = joined.DefaultIfEmpty() })
            .ToList();
```

In my test data, there are NO matches.  So, I have this code:

```
            var difference = groupjoin.FirstOrDefault(g => 
            g.a == null);
```

I was expecting `difference` to be an anonymous object with a "c" property that was an object from `cData`, and an "a" property that was null.

However, `g.a == null` is never true, so `FirstOrDefault` gives me a null for `difference`.  `g.a` is, in fact, a `DefaultIfEmptyIterator` and `g.a.ToList()` gives me a count of 1, and `g.a.ToList[0] == null` is true.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Your assumption will be correct if you use `Join`. `GroupJoin` is different, see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how `DefaultIfEmpty` works. This method returns a collection with one element (type parameter's default) if the collection is empty, not null.

So in your case, if there are no matches, `joined.DefaultIfEmpty()` will return a collection with just one element, that is `null` for reference types.

If you want `null` when `joined` is empty try something like this:

```
joined.Any() ? joined : null
```

You can read more about `DefaultIfEmpty` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: so with groupjoin we don't need .DefaultIfEmpty() ? it returns results? so this is INCORRECT: `x.GroupJoin(y.DefaultIfEmpty(), o=>o.ycode, i=>i.ycode, new {x, y})` and this is Correct: `x.GroupJoin(y, o=>o.ycode, i=>i.ycode, new {x, y.Any()?y:null})` ??? `y.FirstOrDefault()` in my case which only one record is in other collection, and the key is in main table